# database structure for letting users place tags on their profile?

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

I have a users table with the following information

```
users (id, username, password, email, location, about, sex, age, etc.)
```

I would like to let users add a maximum of five tags to their profile.

The tags will store their interests. And will be used to suggest users to other users based on similar interests.

Should I create a field, in my users table, where they can store all five tags or should I create a separate tags table with a different row for each tag corresponding to the `user_id` of who it belongs to?

If I choose option 1, how can I store the tags separated by commas in PHP? I would create variable that stores the tag name, and then how do I add this in the correct format?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Storying multiple tags in one field could cause problems.

Personally I would make a new table:

```
tags (id, userid, tag)
```

As you can see it uses the userid as the foreign key. It will also be easier to count them etc.

Comment: ok, thanks. i am not familiar with foreign keys, what is the pros and cons of using a foreign key as userid vs simply inserting the userid of the person who made the post as a normal entry? how would i insert the foreign key vs entering the normal id?

Comment: `userid` would match the id of the user who entered the tag. The only reason I've called it `userid` is for clarity reasons. `id` would be a unique id for each tag record. I would assume a user would be logged in and you would hold their 'id' in maybe a session variable? So when you added a tag into the database, you would simply set 'userid' as the value that the session variable holds. I'm thinking maybe you planned to do something similar, but weren't aware it was called a foreign key :)

Comment: ok yes that makes sense. thanks for the clarification. i thought the foreign key might mean it was in some way automatically linked/joined with the id field from the users table.